# Python kwarg shared instance

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I've noticed an effect I didn't expect with kwargs in python and I wanted to confirm I have fully understood it/get a better understanding.

My example code

```
class Obj(object):
    pass

def Foo(kwarg=Obj()):
     return kwarg

def Bar(kwarg=None):
     if not kwarg:
         kwarg = Obj()
     return kwarg
```

Now I come to understand only recently these functions do something different.

Unless kwarg is passed when it is called, Foo will return the same instance of Obj every time, while Bar will return different instances of Obj each time.

Does this happens because the keyword arguments are assigned to the resolved value of their RHS at compile time resulting in the same in the same instance being returned each time.

Answer (score 2):

You got it, but there is no compilation in vanilla python. :) Here is quote form "The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python":

> Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say, Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: And that is the reason why you usually want to do it like in your `Bar` class except from the rare case, that you want all instances to have a reference to the same object as it's default.